# How can I create a condition where a command is executed if my string length is more than one character using Freemarker?

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I would like to create a condition where if my string is more than one character a command is executed. I think my format is incorrect. I am using the following code:

```
                <#list kirt as x>
                  <#if x.length >1>
                    ${x}<#if x_has_next>,</#if>
                  </#if>
               </#list>
```

But I keep getting this error:

Exception when trying to transform with the FTL template! freemarker.core.NonHashException: For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar): ==> x [in template "core/webinars/gmlwebinar.ftl" at line 119, column 36] ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: #if x.length [in template "core/webinars/gmlwebinar.ftl" at line 119, column 31] ----

I'm not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<#if x?length gt 1>
```

because:

- FTL normally doesn't expose methods for which there's an `?something`
  thing
- The `>` would close the tag